# Error with creating IAM role when terraform applying a lambda function to localstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-cli, localstack

I have the following directory hierarchy:

```
Lambda
│
├── adduserpost
│   ├── venv
│   ├── .terraform
│   ├── .terraform.lock.hcl
│   ├── lambda_function_add_user_post.zip
│   ├── lambda-addUserPost.tf
│   ├── lambdafunctions.py
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   └── terraform.tfstate.backup
└── ...
```

`lambda-addUserPost.tf` has this content:

```
 provider "aws" {
      region                  = "us-east-1"  # Change to your desired region
      access_key              = "test"       # Access key for LocalStack
      secret_key              = "test"       # Secret key for LocalStack
      skip_credentials_validation = true
      skip_requesting_account_id = true
    
    
      endpoints {
        dynamodb    = "http://localhost:4566"  # LocalStack DynamoDB endpoint
        lambda      = "http://localhost:4566"
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_lambda_function" "add_user_post" {
      function_name = "AddUserPost"
      handler       = "addUserPost.lambda_handler"
      runtime       = "python3.8"
      filename      = data.archive_file.lambda_function_add_user_post.output_path  # ZIP file containing your Python code
      role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.arn
      source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda_function_add_user_post.output_path)
    
      environment {
        variables = {
          TABLE_NAME = "UserProfileTable"  # Update with your DynamoDB table name
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_execution_role" {
      name = "lambda_execution_role"
    
      assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
        Version = "2012-10-17",
        Statement = [
          {
            Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
            Effect = "Allow",
            Principal = {
              Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      })
    }
    
    
    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_dynamodb_access" {
      policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
      role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.name
    }
    
    
    
    data "archive_file" "lambda_function_add_user_post" {
      type          = "zip"
      source_dir    = "${path.module}"
      output_path   = "${path.module}/lambda_function_add_user_post.zip"
    }
```

As far as I can tell, this is configured properly. However, running `terraform apply` gives me an error:

```
│ Error: creating IAM Role (lambda_execution_role): InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
│       status code: 403, request id: e47ff97c-1fd3-46e7-b379-3b27d2cbb40f
│ 
│   with aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role,
│   on lambda-addUserPost.tf line 30, in resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_execution_role":
```

I don't understand why I am receiving this error. What security token? I have `access_key` and `secret_key` with placeholder values, but its localstack. Why do I need a valid security token? If needed, why is mine not properly set up? How can I fix this? I am able to terraform apply a `dynamoDB` table with no issues.

Comment: check clock on your computer. It may be not up to date.

Comment: Is this a sincere suggestion? I don't understand.

Comment: Local machine clock is EST and localstack is GMT, but they're otherwise sync'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to make sure your localstack, terraform and aws provider versions are up to date.

Next, I suspect the issue is that the IAM endpoint is not configured, so when terraform tries to create the IAM resources you have, it tried to connect to AWS.

```
endpoints {
        dynamodb    = "http://localhost:4566"
        lambda      = "http://localhost:4566"
        iam         = "http://localhost:4566"
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was so simple and yet I could not find this suggested anywhere! All tutorials I saw describing lambda functions never set the endpoints for IAM. Or if they did I somehow missed it.

Comment: No worries! The `iam` resources you were creating was the hint.
You can use this configuration to avoid this in the future: [Localstack Endpoint Configuration](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/terraform/#endpoint-configuration) or use the [tflocal wrapper script](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/terraform/#tflocal-wrapper-script) so all of this works out of the box without extra terraform code :)